# ES6 Setting Properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, ecmascript-6

I've looked into it, and it seems as though ES6 doesn't have the ability to set properties of a class, and return that class?

```
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
    }
    update(value) {
        // logic
        this.y = value;
        return value;
    }
}

var x = new MyClass();
console.log(x.update(1));
```

With the above, `x` will keep y as 0, even though setting `y` to `1`. `console.log` will put out `1`, but `y` is never actually updated. Calling `x.y` will result in `0`.

I've also attempted returning the class, yet that doesn't work either.

```
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
    }
    update(value) {
        // logic
        this.y = value;
        return this;
    }
}

var x = new MyClass();
x = x.update(1);
```

Using `console.log(x)` afterwards would once again result in `y` being `0`, and not `1`.

I'm aware of `set` and `get`, but then I wouldn't be able to perform any logic within `update()` or return anything.

Is this intended, or am I completely doing it wrong?

**I would like to note that I'm using NodeJS**.

I am doing something such as:

```
class.js ->
    module.exports = /*class MyClass{}*/ (the above MyClass code)

app.js ->
    let MyClass = require('class');

    let x = new MyClass();
    x.update(1);

    console.log(x) (this returns the same value as x before calling update())
```

Comment: Your code shouldn't work as you're missing the `class` keyword & you can't call a class as a function

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue: http://puu.sh/pOHGf/3f57163da1.png

Comment: @Kondax Are you sure you are checking `x.y` not `x.x`?

Comment: Yeah, I'm checking x.y. I'll add some more information to the op.

Comment: "this returns the same value as x before calling update()" `x` is referencing the same value. What is the output of `console.log(x.y)`?

Comment: `0`, since it seems to never change `x`.

Comment: You are not changing `x`. You are trying to change `x.y`. Since you don't want to show your actuall code I'm voting to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

> Calling `x.y` will result in `0`

No it does. This suggests that your `// logic` is flawed. If there is no extra logic, the `x.y` property does end up as `1`.

Comment: My `// logic` just checks the minimum and maximum of `value` and returns an int if either is not met.

Comment: @Kondax then maybe the logic for checking min/max value always succeeds. The only way to know for sure is if you post the code.

Comment: @Kondax: That's exactly what I'm saying, that logic might easily be flawed. Maybe an assignment instead of a comparison with `0`?

Comment: @Bergi Yeah I looked over that, but it's fine - just `if a < b return c` etc.

Comment: @Kondax still, as you can see, the code that you've provided works fine. So the problem must be with the code you haven't provided. There's no real reason to hide that code from us, it's probably not like you're keeping massive business secrets there. We can't help you if you don't show us what you're doing.

Comment: @Kondax: Well a `return c` would prevent the property assignment for example… Either you post the exact code you are using, or all we can tell you is that it doesn't happen.

Comment: @MatisLepik I'm not, it's just quite large so I thought it would be best to provide a 'mock' of what I'm using. I'll attach the actual code.

Comment: @Kondax: We're looking for it

Answer (score 0):

It works!

```
 var x =new MyClass();
    console.log(x.update(1)); //1
    console.log(x.y); //1
```